# How do you add add commands after a loop Breaks?

Tags: clipboard, autohotkey, break

I have a loop running, and in the middle of the loop I have the command

```
IfInString, Clipboard, Stop
  Break
```

How would I issue commands after this? Adding text after the body didn't work. I'm very new to autohotkey.

Answer (score 2):

When inside a `Loop` and a `Break` is hit, the code execution will go directly to the code beyond the loop.

```
Loop
{
    IfInString, Clipboard, Stop
        Break
    /*
    Some other stuff could be here,
    but this does not run if the break is hit
    */
}
; Code execution continues here
Msgbox, Stop was found in the clipboard
```

Comment: You've narrated everything just as it happens!  This is correct.